# Eclipse on Ubuntu 12.10 - BG color of Java editor left margin

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, colors

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10, one of the things that's been annoying me is the background color of the left margin of the Eclipse Java editor window. It's pretty much white, which makes it difficult to see where the actual left edge of the editor window ends and the margin begins. Screenshot:

[image: Eclipse Ubuntu]

I've looked through all the Eclipse color settings and also all the "Gnome Color Chooser" settings and I don't see where I would change this. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to go to `Windows->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors` and find the section called `Appearance color options`. You will want to change the Selection background color. This will also change the background of the main document, but this will make where one section begins and ends well defined. You can experiment with these settings and the settings under `Java->Editor` until you get the color scheme you want.

Comment: It's not the selection background color that I'm trying to change. Selected text is not the issue. I'm trying to change the background color of the left vertical margin that in my screenshot contains the little "collapse" icon to the left of "public boolean....".